# Compare attributes inside a XACML policy

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I'm developing an XACML policy and I'm using a sun.xacml library.
i want to compare two attributes: one for the subject and one for the resource for permit the access on the resources.

I have generated this XACML file

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Policy PolicyId="GeneratedPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides">
  <Description>Policy che permette la lettura del file ai client che hanno un livello di permesso maggiore o uguale al livello di permesso del file richiesto</Description>
  <Target>
<Subjects>
  <AnySubject/>
</Subjects>
<Resources>
  <AnyResource/>
</Resources>
<Actions>
  <Action>
 <ActionMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
   <ActionAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
 </ActionMatch>
  </Action>
</Actions>
  </Target>
  <Rule RuleId="canRead" Effect="Permit">
<Target>
  <Subjects>
 <AnySubject/>
  </Subjects>
  <Resources>
 <AnyResource/>
  </Resources>
  <Actions>
 <Action>
   <ActionMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
  <ActionAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
   </ActionMatch>
 </Action>
  </Actions>
</Target>
<Condition FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-greater-than-or-equal">
  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">
 <SubjectAttributeDesignator AttributeId="level-permission" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  </Apply>
  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">4</AttributeValue>
</Condition>
  </Rule>
  <Rule RuleId="FinalRule" Effect="Deny"/>
</Policy>
```

The problem is that a resource have a level-permission and i want to compare subject's level-permission and resource's level-permission but i don't know how do it.

thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to do. What are you referring to by 'level-permission'? Is it some sort of access level like you would have in a MLS model, where each subject would have a (maximum) access level (secret, top secret,...), and each resource would have a (minimum) access level as well?

Comment: Can you express in plain old English (or Italian) what your end goal is? For instance: a user with the role==manager wants to do the action==view on documents of type X if and only document classification < user clearance.

Comment: Also, this looks like a XACML 1.1 or XACML 2.0 policy. What did you use to generate the policy? Did you look into ALFA?

Comment: ogni subjects e risorsa ha un livello di permesso, la policy mi deve dire se il subject può leggere la risorsa.

Comment: Each subject and resources have a level permission and the policy goal is if the subject can read the resources.

Comment: @AngeloCapasso was my answer helpful? Don't forget to mark it as accepted and/or vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Whenever you need to compare 2 attributes together e.g. `user-clearance` and `resource-classification`, you need to use a XACML `Condition`. You did try to do that in your example but you compared the attribute to a static value.

Here is a simple example in ALFA ([Axiomatics Language for Authorization](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html)).

```
policy documentAccess{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule allowAccessIfClearanceSufficient{
        condition user.clearance>document.classification
        permit
    }
}
```

I define my attributes as follows:

```
    attribute classification{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "document.classification"
        type = integer
    }
```

and

```
    attribute clearance{
        category = subjectCat
        id = "user.clearance"
        type = integer
    }
```

Note that I use an integer here instead of string. It's more efficient and safer.

The output in XACML 3.0 is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.documentAccess"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description />
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target />
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.documentAccess.allowAccessIfClearanceSufficient">
        <xacml3:Description />
        <xacml3:Target />
        <xacml3:Condition>
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any">
                <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-greater-than"/>
                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                    AttributeId="user.clearance"
                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                    MustBePresent="false"
                />
                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                    AttributeId="document.classification"
                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                    MustBePresent="false"
                />
            </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Condition>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```